# Print a part of line if operation of sed and grep is true

Tags: linux, sed, grep, exim

Trying to find spammers in exim mainlog.
Mainlog has mail IDs and Subjects something like below.

```
username1@example.com S==thi#s i $s @a Su~bJec%t
username2@example2.com S==thi#s i ^s an*ot+her Su~bj)ec%t
```

What I am trying to do is take the subject, remove all the symbols, space using sed and grep for keywords. If satisfied, then print mail ID. 
I am successful in removing all the symbols, space and grep the keywords, but the problem is symbols from mail IDs (@ and .) are also removed. 
So my question is how to apply `sed` and `grep` only to subjects `S==thi#s i ^s an*ot+her Su~bj)ec%t` and if satisfied print mail ID without affecting its symbols.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank You... This works form me...
awk -F 'S==' -v k1=this '{gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $2); if ($2 ~ k1) print $1}'

Comment: gsub() expects an RE as it's first arg so you should use RE delimiters (`/`) instead of string delimiters (`"`) unless you have a very good reason to require string delimiters, e.g. you are concatenating an explicit string with a variable. Also, use `[^[:alnum:]]`, don't hard-code `[^A-Za-z0-9]`. Finally, the awk-ish way to write a condition+action is not with an `if` statement. So, that script should be written `'{gsub(/[^[:alnum:]]/, "", $2)} $2 ~ k1{print $1}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be tricky with `sed`, if even possible. If you're ok with `awk` instead:

```
awk -F' S==' -v k1=this '{gsub("[][()#$@~% ]", "", $2); if ($2 ~ k1) print $1}'
```

If you want to remove all non-alphanumeric characters, then it's better to write like this:

```
awk -F' S==' -v k1=this '{gsub("[^[:alnum:]]", "", $2); if ($2 ~ k1) print $1}'
```

If your version of `awk` doesn't support `[:alnum:]` then you can write like this instead:

```
awk -F' S==' -v k1=this '{gsub("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "", $2); if ($2 ~ k1) print $1}'
```

Explanation:

- Using `S==` as the field separator to split mail ID and subject parts
- Passing in a keyword "this" in the `k1` variable. You could use any other keyword or multiple keywords with more `-v` parameters in the same format, for example `-v k2=something`
- Remove all the symbols from the 2nd field with `gsub`
- If the 2nd field matches the keyword in `k1`, then print the first field (= the mail ID)

I hope this helps.

Comment: But I need to remove all the symbols from the subject. How do I remove these symbols []'"\

Comment: This works. But still can't remove ^

awk -F 'S==' -v k1=this '{gsub("[^[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $2); if ($2 ~ k1) print $1}'

Answer (score 0):

Before: your grep/sed  (could be in your sed treatment but before your action)

```
sed 's/@/(at)/1
: dot
   s/^\([^ ]*\)\.\([^ ]*\) /\1(dot)\2 /
   t dot'
```

after your grep sed (could be in your sed treatment but aftyer your action)

```
sed 's/(dot)/./g;s/(at)/@/g'
```

assuming there is no `(dot)` and `(at)` in your subject. Nearly any other pattern could be used like `#at#` or `§1§` or `:a:` instead (just not use specal sed char like `+.{[$^`